# Azure .NET SDK - List all virtual machines, failed to authenticate

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-sdk-.net

Using the new [Windows Azure SDK for .NET](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-net/), I want to get a list of all virtual machines.

Piecing together the early documentation, here's what I came up with:

```
// This is a custom cert I made locally. I uploaded it to Azure's Management Certificates and added it to my local computer's cert store, see screenshot below.
X509Certificate2 myCustomCert = await this.GetAzureCert();
var credentials = new CertificateCloudCredentials(mySubscriptionId, myCustomCert);

using (var cloudServiceClient = CloudContext.Clients.CreateCloudServiceManagementClient(credentials))
{
    credentials.InitializeServiceClient(cloudServiceClient); // Is this required? The next call fails either way.

    // This line fails with exception: "The server failed to authenticate the request. Verify that the certificate is valid and is associated with this subscription."
    var services = await cloudServiceClient.CloudServices.ListAsync(CancellationToken.None);
}
```

My first thought was the cert was bad, but I am able to successfully call the Azure REST API using my custom certificate. As you can see below, it is properly added to the Azure Management Certificates and associated with my subscription:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another option - rather than upload a cert, try pulling your management cert out of your publishsettings file and using the X509Certificate's constructor that takes a byte[]. Then, pass that parameter the result of a call to Convert.FromBase64String, passing it the string representation of your management certificate from your publishsettings file.

Also, take a look at the Compute management client rather than the Cloud Service Management client. There are more features specific to the compute stack in that client at this time. The code below is a demonstration of such an approach. Note, my _subscriptionId and _managementCert fields are both strings, and I just hard-code them to the values from my publishsettings file as I described above.

```
public async static void ListVms()
{
    using (var client = new ComputeManagementClient(
        new CertificateCloudCredentials(_subscriptionId, 
            new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(_managementCert)))
        ))
    {
        var result = await client.HostedServices.ListAsync();
        result.ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.ServiceName));
    }
}
```

Comment: You rock, Brady! #winning

Comment: No sweat whatsoever. Don't hesitate to reach out if you encounter any other weirdness. Feel free to report any issues via our GitHub site, too.

Answer (score 1):

There's a parameterless ListAsync method that's an extension method. Try importing the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management namespace (or the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Compute namespace). Once you see the parameterless ListAsync method you should be good. I'll also mock up some code to resemble what you're trying to accomplish and offer up a more comprehensive answer by the end of the day.

Comment: Also - the InitializeServiceClient call isn't required. Reading your question more thoroughly it looks like your cert might not have been pulled in fully. Here's an idea - grab your publishsettings file, open it up. Pull out the subscription ID and the Base64-encoded cert string from the file for the subscription in question and try it. If that works, it confirms your cert didn't "land" properly. Again, I'll write up some code today to more fully answer this but wanted to answer your "internal question." :)

Comment: OK, I'll give that a shot and let you know. Thanks for helping so quickly.

Comment: Copying the base64-encoded management cert string and using that worked. Now I just need to figure out why that cert works, when my local cert doesn't.

Comment: Brady, maybe you want to add your comment about using the base64-encoded cert string as an answer. Then I can mark yours as the answer.

Comment: I just noticed that while the call is returning success, it shows zero results, even though I do have virtual machines running. Should  cloudServiceClient.CloudServices.ListAsync return the list of virtual machines? I guess I'm confused by the term "cloud service".

Comment: No problem. I'll do that now, and add some additional code that might be another option for you.